# toggle in-call bar stretch splash screen default logo in xcode 10?

Tags: ios, ios11, xcode10, splash-screen

When i enable the toggle in-call bar from hardware option when first splash loads it size changes i need to fix it without stretch the logo.i have already tried with didchangestatus bar frame method in app-delegate file but do not happen anything.I am greatly appreciated for help best regards.

[image: [my splash screen logo image squeezed while toggle in-call status bar comes in normal it display perfect.]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZIOy.png)

Comment: If your logo is an image then give fix width and height change aspect to fit or fill as per your requirement.

Comment: @AbhishekJadhav - i have already tried that but still problem persists .

Comment: This is now your app problem. Open other app and check still issue is present.

Comment: @kalpeshsatasiya - there is no problem in app having same issue.